# taking padding off Li's, but still shows spacing on the bottom

Tags: html, css

I tried messing with the `subMenu-link` padding by giving it a `margin` & `padding` a `0` but no luck.

CSS:

```
#side-navigation {
    list-style:none;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:11px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width: 100%;
}
#side-navigation li {
    padding: 8px 5px 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.lock {
    background: url('../images/lock.png') no-repeat center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top:-5px;
    margin-left:5%;
}
.subMenu-link {
    list-style: none;
    padding-bottom: 10;
    margin: 0;
}
li.subMenu span{
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul id="side-navigation">                       
        <li class="subMenu"><i class="lock"></i><span class="title">User Account</span>
        <span class="toggle">+</span>
            <ul class="subMenu-link">
                <li>One Link</li>
                <li>One Link</li>
                <li>One Link</li>
                <li>One Link</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

What it shows:

http://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/5f6ec1da326aab4911feed285add0b4b.png

I'm trying to get the li's for "one link" not to have some much padding on the bottom.

Comment: Your padding on the `li`s is coming from `#side-navigation li`: you've got `8px` on the top, and `5px` on the bottom. So you're going to have `13px` between the *One Link* texts.

Comment: you do have padding-bottom: 10; on the subMenu-link class. why not try removing that

Answer (score 0):

`.subMenu-link` is the `ul` which doesn't even have any padding/margin (except for `padding-left`) in the first place therefore adding `margin: 0px` and `padding: 0px` to `.subMenu-link` won't work. The padding has been applied to the `<li>`'s which you can remove by using the following CSS:

```
#side-navigation li {
     padding: 0px;
}
```